# Refresh Image at Interval in Folium ImageOverlay

Tags: python, image, leaflet, folium

***Important Code***

Consider the following code to generate a map with a raster/image overlay using Folium. This currently utilizes Rioxarray to load a GeoTIFF, compute its bounds, and provide the array for coloring prior to ImagerOverlay:

import sys, folium, matplotlib
import rioxarray as rxr, geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import cm, colors as clr

```
dst_crs = 'EPSG:4326'
file = '/path/to/dir/somefile.tif'
statesgis = gpd.read_file('/path/to/dir/st_us.shp').to_crs(dst_crs).to_json()
countiesgis = gpd.read_file('/path/to/dir/cnt_us.shp').to_crs(dst_crs).to_json()

states_json = folium.features.GeoJson(data=statesgis, style_function=lambda x: {"fillColor":"transparent", "color": "#000000", "weight":2}, control=True, name="States GIS")
counties_json = folium.features.GeoJson(data=countiesgis, style_function=lambda x: {"fillColor":"transparent", "color": "#000000", "weight":1}, control=True, name="Counties GIS")

with rxr.open_rasterio(file, lock=False, mask_and_scale=True) as da:
    da = da.rio.reproject(dst_crs)
    data = (da.data[0] * 1.8) + 32
    bounds = da.rio.bounds()
    minlon, minlat, maxlon,  maxlat = bounds

center_lat = minlat - ((minlat - maxlat) / 2)
center_lon = minlon - ((minlon - maxlon) / 2)
values = [-70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
norm_da = (data - min(values)) / (max(values) - min(values))
colorlist = [(0, '#b7b1b9d9'),(0.05, '#4e008bd9'), (0.11, '#f03c99d9'), (0.16, '#ed77b8d9'),(0.21, '#d0b6d9d9'),(0.26, '#97f7f7d9'),(0.32, '#1674f0d9'),(0.365, '#3727a1d9'),(0.366, '#520980d9'),(0.42, '#f000bcd9'),(0.47, '#9c060ed9'), (0.53, '#ffffffd9'), (0.57, '#1279ffd9'), (0.61, '#00f0f0d9'), (0.65, '#befa00d9'), (0.69, '#ffff00d9'), (0.73, '#ff8000d9'), (0.77, '#f51400d9'), (0.82, '#800000d9'), (0.88, '#732c45d9'), (0.94, '#fc9090d9'), (1, '#fcf7f7d9')]
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(values),vmax=max(values))
cm = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('TempRamp',colorlist, N=256)
color_da = cm(norm_da)

map = folium.Map(location = [center_lat, center_lon], tiles='Stamen Terrain', zoom_start = 7)
folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(color_da, [[minlat, minlon], [maxlat, maxlon]], mercator_project=True, interactive=False, opacity=0.65).add_to(map)
states_json.add_to(map)
counties_json.add_to(map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)

map.save("/path/to/dir/map.html")
```

This produces the following output, which looks as follows:

[image: foliumimage]

***Question***

In the [documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html), I've discovered that Folium can plot images from websites/servers, which introduces a lot of flexibility. Is it possible in Folium to apply an option that refreshes an image file in ImageOverlay at specific time intervals? Please note I'm prepared to convert this GeoTIFF to a PNG/JPG with coloring already applied in order to remove the rioxarray call.